# Ansible - tilde as variable

Tags: jinja2, ansible

I'm trying to put a tilde character in a variable that I'm going to use in a template in Ansible and for the life of me I cannot achieve what I want, as the tilde is being expanded in all sorts of weird ways.

What I want to achieve is to have `some_var` defined in my vars file so that I can use it in a template like so:

`random_setting: "{{ some_var }}"` and get this as a result: `random_setting: ~`, i.e. pure tilde, no quotes added.

Instead I keep getting this: `random_setting: '~'` (which is not acceptable for my use case) or this: `random_setting: ''` (which is just as bad).

My question is: how do I escape the tilde character, so that I can use it without it being either surrounded by quotes or expanded in some obscure way? I've already tried a few tricks including encoding the `~` character with base64 and using the `| b64decode` filter in Ansible, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Add playbook example, please. Assigning `~` to `some_var` is as simple as `some_var: '~'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be confusing the real value with the output of Ansible.

If you run this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    var1: "~"
  tasks:
    - template: src=tilde-template.j2 dest=result.txt
```

with `tilde-template.j2`:

```
{{ var1 }}
```

And check the contents of `result.txt` it will contain just the tilde.

Comment: Ah, not entirely, but close. What betrayed me was the habit of quoting the variables everywhere in Ansible -- even in Jinja2 templates, which, it turns out, is an overkill. So it turned out to be a trivial thing in the end. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction :)